# Need to get bullets from word tables to excel using interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

So I've been trying to learn how to use Interop (and programming in general for that matter).  Basically I have these tables in my Word docs that I need to export to Excel.

I've gotten the basic text to export to Excel, but my tables in Word have a fair amount of formatting, mainly bulleted Lists in some of the cells that I need to keep or rebuild possibly once I get them into excel??

Here is my code.  This exports the text obviously.  Through some research I was able to get the bullets and indents and see them in a richtextbox (see commented code).  I need this to work cell by cell.  I can't build everything in a Array and pass it over to Excel.

It is a constraint in the application I am trying to update.  The code here is just a test case.  My question is, how do I get this to export or rebuild in excel?

I have found some articles on the subject but nothing that has helped me enough to get through this hump which is why im asking here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook excelworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\mytest.xlsx");
    Excel._Worksheet excelworkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

    excelApp.Visible = true;

    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object path = txbxFilePath1.Text;
    object readOnly = true;
    var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
                               ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                               ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                               ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
                               ref miss);

    foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
    {
        for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            for (int mycols = 1; mycols <= tb.Columns.Count; mycols++)
            {
                var cells = tb.Cell(row, mycols).Range.Paragraphs;

                foreach (Paragraph para in cells)
                {
                    //string bulltxt = para.Range.Text;
                    //string leftIndent = para.LeftIndent.ToString();
                    //string bulletStr = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
                    //rTxBxResult.AppendText(leftIndent + "\t" + bulletStr + "\t" + para.Range.Text);
                }

                excelworkSheet.Cells[row, mycols] = tb.Cell(row, mycols).Range.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean export and rebuild? are you not closing the word and excel app intentionally?

Comment: @Jelly export/transfer/move....  Call it whatever.  I have tables in a word document that I need to get into a excel spreadsheet.  I need to keep the formatting, mainly the bulleted items.  there's no close in this because it's just a POC to get the bulleted items in excel.  The app Im actually updating has all the necessary closing statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a friend we came up with 'a' solution.  Basically I've created a custom class and used that instead of trying to do the whole thing through interop which I found limiting for this.  There's a little cheat at the end where I used '*' and '-' for my bullet characters.  There is a way to actually send keys to excel using some kind of application send key method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.sendkeys(v=office.11).aspx) but I just didn't have the time today.

I added comments to the code to help. Hope someone finds this useful.

```
    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook excelworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\myxlspreadsheet");
        Excel._Worksheet excelworkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;



        excelApp.Visible = true;

        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = txbxFilePath1.Text;
        object readOnly = true;
        var docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, 
                                   ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                                   ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                                   ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                                   ref miss);

        //Get the tables in the word Document
        foreach (Table tb in docs.Tables)
        {                
            for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int mycols = 1; mycols <= tb.Columns.Count; mycols++)
                {
                    var cells = tb.Cell(row, mycols).Range.Paragraphs;

                    //Create a List using your custom formatter Class
                    List<Formatter> lFormatter = new List<Formatter>();                   
                    foreach (Paragraph para in cells)
                    {
                        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
                        formatter.strCellText = para.Range.Text;
                        formatter.flIndent = para.LeftIndent;
                        formatter.strBullet = para.Range.ListFormat.ListString;
                        rTxBxResult.AppendText(formatter.strCombine);
                        lFormatter.Add(formatter);
                    }
                    for (int i =0; i< lFormatter.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Formatter formatter = lFormatter[i];
                        if(i==0)
                            excelworkSheet.Cells[row, mycols] = ((string)(excelworkSheet.Cells[row, mycols] as Excel.Range).Value2) + formatter.strCombine;
                        else
                            excelworkSheet.Cells[row, mycols] = ((string)(excelworkSheet.Cells[row, mycols] as Excel.Range).Value2) + Environment.NewLine + formatter.strCombine;
                    }

                }                    
            }
        }
    }

}

//Use this class to store the collected values from the rows and colums of the word table
public class Formatter
{
    public string strCellText;
    public string strIndent = "";
    public float flIndent;
    public string strBullet;
    //Combine the pieces together and manipulate the strings as needed
    public string strCombine
    {
        get 
        {
            //first indent is 36 so 1 tab, second indent is 72 so 2 tabs, etc
            //alternate * and dashes for bullet marks in excel using odd and even numbers
            decimal newIndent = Math.Round((decimal)(flIndent / 36));
            for (int i = 0; i < newIndent; i++)
            {
                strIndent = strIndent + "  ";
            }
            if (newIndent == 0)
                strBullet = "";
            else if (IsOdd((int)newIndent))
                strBullet="*";
            else
                strBullet = "-";
            return strIndent + strBullet + strCellText;                
        }
    }

    public static bool IsOdd(int value)
    {
    return value % 2 != 0;
    }


}
```